# Prove that a set X is closed if and only if it contains its accumulation points.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Problem**: Prove that a set $X$ is closed if and only if $X^a \subset X$.

**Proof:** Let $X$ be a closed set and suppose that $x \in X^a$. Then $\exists \{x_n\} \subset X$ with $x_n \neq x $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$. By definition, $x$ is a limit point of $X$, and $x\in X$. Hence $X^a \subset X$.

Now suppose that $X^a \subset X$ and let $x$ be a limit point of $X$. Then $\exists \{x_n\} \subset X$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x.$ If $\{x_n\}$ is an eventually constant sequence, then $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $n \geq N$, so $x\in X$. Thus suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is not eventually constant. It may still be the case that $x_n=x$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Construct a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $x_{n_k}\neq x$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$. If it were not possible to construct such a sequence, then $x_n \neq x$ for only finitely many $n\in \mathbb{N},$ which would imply that $\{x_n\}$ is eventually constant. We have that $\{x_{n_k}\}\to x$ because subsequences converge to the same limit as their parent sequences, so by definition $x$ is then an accumulation point. Thus $x\in X$ and $X$ is closed.

I would appreciate any feedback on this proof, especially the second part. Thanks!

---

**Disclaimer:** I know that this question has been asked elsewhere, but the provided answers use concepts that have not yet been introduced in the book I am studying. Specifically, I don't know anything about the relationship between open and closed sets right now. As such, I would like to try proving it using only the concepts that I know right now.

Let $X^a$ denote the set of accumulation points of $X$. For this discussion, assume $X \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Definition 1:** A point $x$ is a *limit point* of $X$ if and only if there exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset X$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = x.$.

**Definition 2:** A set $X$ is *closed* if and only if it contains all of its limit points.

**Definition 3:** A point $x$ is an accumulation point of $X$ if and only if there exists $\{x_n\} \subset X$ with $x_n \neq x$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = x$.

Comment: Could you please tell us what your definitions for closed and open are? They tend to be slippery, in that there's one canonical definition on the level of general topology, but at the level of, say, Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, there's a whole bunch of equivalent ones.

Comment: My apologies -- I'll edit the question.

Comment: I omitted the definition of an open set because, as I said, it has not yet been defined in the book I am using.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: It's fine. I suggest for  further reading you have a look at the first chapter of a text on general topology to see the general definitions of "a topology  on a set" and "open set" , "closed set" and "continuous function".  It is more general than  the topics of convergence  or distances (metrics) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parts of the proof are sound and rigorous. The only constructive feedback I can give you regards minor and more subjective aspects of your proof.

One general selection you can make that will assist in both of the comments I have is to define the set of limit points. Suppose you call the set of limit points $X^{l}$. It follows from your definition of a closed set that a set $X$ is closed iff $X^{l} \subset X$. This definition can simplify and clarify your work.

My first comment regards the following line: "By definition, $x$ is a limit point of $X$, and $x\in X$. Hence $X^a \subset X$." This is entirely accurate, but in my opinion seems a bit unclear. Specifically, the fact that $x \in X$ stems from the fact that $X$ is closed--i.e., $X^{l} \subset X$. Using our new definition, you can simply state that "By definition, $x \in X^{l}$, giving $X^{a} \subset X^{l}$. Since $X$ is closed, $X^{l} \subset X$, thus $X^{a} \subset X$.

Similarly, when you prove the reverse side of the implication, you can begin by letting some $x \in X^{l}$, and conclude with $x \in X^{a}$ implying that $X^{l} \subset X^{a}$. From your initial assumption that $X^{a} \subset X$, you then have $X^{l} \subset X$, which indicates that $X$ is closed. Once again, these are very minor suggestions, but I think that they can enhance the clarity of a few areas in your proof, and condense them.